# What systems exist worldwide for providing a higher education degree based on examinations, assignments or demonstrated competence, but not classtime?

Tags: degree

I am looking for responses naming any single university, degree program, strategy or other type of degree certification in which you receive a degree for completing (large) assignments or passing exams, but there is no mandatory “classtime”.

The overall point is a degree that is not time-oriented. If you are required to turn in homework assignments regularly and take quizzes, that means a regular obligatory workload punctuating your daily life. The details may vary, but the idea is obtaining a degree by demonstrating in fewer distinct submissions, even if more intensive in involvement, that you possess competence. That could be a few major projects and a few major exams. It’s ok if completion of those validating requirements is only offered at certain times in the year.

I would specifically tailor the question to Bachelor’s degrees, but am open to hearing about Masters and Ph.D.‘s out of curiosity.

To expand, most Bachelor’s degrees are structured temporally, based on ongoing units requiring regular participation, which grant course credit contributing to your degree, and virtually all appear to be 3-5 years in length.

But is that just incidental, just because no university system in the world thought it was worthwhile, useful, in-demand, or effective, to design a Bachelor’s degree dispensed for demonstrating skill in a field of knowledge, in case someone already had acquired skill?

Or is it a widely held tenant of pedagogy that a Bachelor’s degree is meant to validate people regarding their capability to perform well and commit to a multi-year program of responsibilities, involvement, and intellectual work?

There are certifications where it suffices completely to pass an exam. For example, language level assessments are required for jobs or university entrance, and are based solely on exam results. You can sign up for and pay for a standalone exam with nothing else attached.

Is it hypothetically possible to do the same thing in any modern university?

To give some examples to prime ideas:

- In Swedish Bachelor’s programs attendance is very commonly not required, regular homework is optional, tuition is free for EU citizens, if you fail a class you can retake it an infinite number of times, if you leave your program you can reenroll years later and continue from where you were, and even large important assignments do not have mandatory deadlines. They are supposed to be submitted by a certain date but there is sometimes no issue with submitting it as late as you want, with no penalty. To an extent, this could amount to a degree based solely on exams and projects, but it is still temporally spread out over years. It’s not the same as proving general knowledge of chemistry with a single (or set of) diagnostic exam(s), sort of like the SAT or GRE.
- There are honorary degrees, but you don’t apply for them and they’re not recognized as official degrees.

Comment: What field? Math? CS? Chemistry, Biology? Or others?

Comment: I don't disagree with the "shopping question" designation, but I wrote an answer before the close vote was complete, so I might as well post it:

Comment: For the Bachelor of Divinity degree at the University of Cambridge, no programme of study is required: a candidate submits a dissertation and the appropriate (modest) fee, and University staff + external referees assess the dissertation against published criteria to be a pass or fail for the degree.  However, to be eligible as a candidate, one must already hold another degree of the University of Cambridge.

Answer (score 1):

University programs typically have two goals:

1. to teach students to be able to do certain stuff
2. to certify that a person with a given degree can do that certain stuff

A program that just consists of tests without any teaching would fail at half its goals.

That is not to say that many programs have a lot (really a lot) of room for improvement when it comes to goal 1.